# Using time-series data in mongoDB for multiple sensor measurements

Tags: mongodb, schema, real-time, time-series

I have an installment of 50 sensors and one sensor gateway.The gateway provides sensor measurements(temperature, humidity etc.) per **minute** with this action going around the clock in this form:

```
{
  measurement_timestamp: ISODate("2013-10-10T23:06:00.000Z"),
  type: “temperature”,
  sensor_data: {
    sensor_0: 19.1,
    …  
    sensor_37: 22,
    sensor_38: 23.7,
    … 
    "sensor_id": sensor_temp
  }
}
```

I'm considering using time-series data as schema design for storing these values in MongoDB according this structure:

```
{
  timestamp_day: ISODate("2013-10-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
  sensor_id: “1”,
  hours: {
    0:{
       0: 22,
       …  
       37: 23.1,
       38: 19,
       … 
       59: sensor_temp
      },
    …  
    1: 
    2:,
    … 
    23:
  }
}
```

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb

Choosing this schema though, means that there will be 50 different documents(one per sensor) updated per minute. The application will need to query for live sensor measurements(latest value from all sensors) and access history for a specified number of sensors. Also there will be the possibility to add sensors to groups. The whole process will be repeated in different installations.

Should there be a different collection per installation or installation id referenced  in documents?

if anyone knows another efficient structure suited for the case please elaborate.

Comment: From your example there will be only one document per day  Instead of using embedded document u can also use array .That is put the temperature value into the sensor array were adding would be easy and querying latest temperature can be done by querying for top 1 in the array

Comment: would it be possible to give me an example with the structure you propose in order to comprehend your suggestion ?

Comment: {  measurement_timestamp: ISODate("2013-10-10T00:00:00.000Z"), type: “temperature”,
  sensor_data: {    sensor_0: [19.1,3,24,,,,,,,23]    … sensor_37:[ 22,,,,22,21]   …    "sensor_id": sensor_temp_array  }}

Comment: It would be useful if u get data from the all sensor at regular interval but if u get data at different time from different sensors this method is inefficient

Comment: Or u could do like this to track time  
{ measurement_timestamp: ISODate("2013-10-10T00:00:00.000Z"), type: “temperature”, sensor_data: { sensor_0: [19.1,3,24,,,,,,,23] … sensor_37:[ 22,,,,22,21] … "sensor_id": sensor_temp_array } , sensor_time: { sensor_0: [8.00,8.01,,,,,,,23.01,24] … sensor_37:[ 22,,,,22.55,24] … "sensor_id": sensor_time_array }    } i don't know how efficient it would be

Comment: First of all thank you for your inputs. Unfortunately, i forgot to mention that the sensors will be added during operation so preallocation of sensor keys in document is not possible. This will lead to document size increase and reallocation so this will be inefficient.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the time-series schema design (the second one) based on the use case you've described. As for whether you should put different installations into different collections, it's hard to say because it's unclear what exactly the difference is between installations and unclear how they will be used. I'm guessing that "installations" are completely separate groups of sensors, so my gut feeling is that they should be separate collections.